# How to focus in Salah?

Tags: salat

In accordance with a verse of the Holy Qur'an, a character of Mo'menin (believers) is Khoshu'(humility) in Salah.

Surah al-Mo'menoon, the first and second verses:

> قَدْ أَفْلَحَ الْمُؤْمِنُونَ
>
> .  الَّذِينَ هُمْ فىِ صَلَاتهِمْ خَاشِعُونَ
>
> Certainly will the believers have succeeded: (1)
>
> They who are during their prayer humbly submissive (2)

Seemingly, concentration in Salah is considered as an aspect of Khoshoo'. Actually paying attention in Salah (concentration) could increase its acceptability for Allah. But unfortunately, it is hard to concentrate during Salah (for many people among me) and in fact our attentions go to different places and matters.

Note:
 **I'm looking for some ways which could help us concentrate during our prayers. Is there any tradition regarding it?** (I mean any tradition about "How to focus in Salah")

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to love saying prayers(namaz)?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21813/how-to-love-saying-prayersnamaz)

Comment: It can be a related link, but not complete the same query as what I am looking for. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alslam Aleikum Brother,

> {Successful indeed are the believers; who, in their prayer, are humbly submissive.} (Al-Mu'minun 23:1-2)

I used to have a similar issue as I couldn't stop thinking of different issues all the time while I’m praying or not, therefore I started to concentrate my thinking towards the versus I’m pronouncing, some particular Ayat I used to recite repeatably once perfectly memorized you happen to recite them unconsciously sometimes, therefore I started memorizing versus which are new to me and recite them in my prayers this has helped.

> {Indeed, I am Allah . There is no deity except Me, so worship Me and establish prayer for My remembrance.} (Ta-Ha 20:14)

While I am in Sojood I keep on thinking how ALLAH has made this world for us and how perfectly tailored it is and how we are in healthy conditions, and how he has guided us to the righteous path and religion otherwise how would we know bad from good.

Remember during Salat you are closer to god than you think, therefore remember how you would like to stand in front of Allah,

there are countless tips and advice's how to do so as well, a simple Google search will provide lots of tips, above I have mentioned my own method which has helped me, inshalah Allah will keep your heart firm on his religion and will bring you closer to him recite this dua and remember Allah before you perform any action.

> “Oh turner of the hearts (Allah, the Most High), keep our hearts firm on your religion”

Shaitan will try to distract you during prayer such distractions will be making you think of different things during prayer or losing count in which rok3ah you are within, refer to the below hadith and remember it while within prayer as it will teach you how to seek refuge to god to get rid of shaytan:

> This happened to one of the companions of the prophet (sahabah) whose name is Uthman Bin Abi Al-Aas, (may Allah be pleased with him), so he came complaining to the Prophet (peace be upon him), and he said: "The Shaitan comes between me and my salat and causes me problems with my recitation." So the Messenger of Allah, (peace be upon him), said: "That is a Shaitan called Khanzab, so if you feel his presence, seek refuge in Allah and blow a mist to your left three times." He said: "I applied this advice and Allah has rid me off him.

Comment: nice response, hope to perform it. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that our Messenger (Peace be upon him) said:

> ... my comfort has been provided in prayer. (Sunan [ibn Majah](http://sunnah.com/nasai/36/1))

And he also said:

> O Bilal, call iqamah for prayer: give us comfort by it. (Sunan [abi Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/213))

So a starting point to perform a good prayer with much concentration is regarding it as a comfort, as a five times daily appointment where you can seek refuge by Allah and ask him and address him ...

For the concentration matter: I'd like to point at the following hadith (from Sunan [ibn Majah](http://sunnah.com/urn/1343090))

> It was narrated that Abu Ayyub said:
> “A man came to the Prophet (ﷺ) and said: ‘O Messenger of Allah, teach me but make it concise.’
>  He said: ‘When you stand to pray, pray like a man bidding farewell. Do not say anything for which you will have to apologize. And give up hope for what other people have.’”

So one way to perform a good prayer is performing it as if it was the last prayer you would perform in your life. Think about it: How much emphasize would you put in it while you perform a dua' or how good would you try to recite the Quran, how much would you be concentrated in doing a very good job?

Among many examples of sahaba who practiced this here are two (note that this is my own translation take it with care):
It was narrated that al-Hussain ibn 'Ali (Peace be upon both of them), when he entering or beginning a prayer used to tremble and his face got a yellow coloring. When asked about it he used to say: Do you know in front of whom I'm now?

> وكان الحسن بن علي رضي الله عنهما إذا دخل في الصلاة ارتعش واصفر لونه ... فإذا سئل عن ذلك قال : أتدرون بين يدي من أقوم الآن؟

While his father Imam 'Ali (May Allah be pleased with him) when he was performing ablution used to tremble. If asked about it he used to say: Now I bear the trust which the heavens and earth and mountains  declined to bear it and feared it ... and I'm bearing it. (Referring to [verse 33:72](http://legacy.quran.com/33/72) )

> وكان أبوه سيدنا علي رضي الله عنه إذا توضأ ارتجف فإذا سئل عن ذلك قال : الآن أحمل الأمانة التي عرضت على السماء والأرض والجبال فأبين أن يحملها وأشفقن منها .... وحملتها أنا

Also try to have in mind the qudsi Hadiths saying:

> ...Allah the Blessed, the Exalted, said, "I have divided the prayer into two halves between me and my slave. One half of it is for Me and one half of it is for My slave, and My slave has what he asks." ...

Which one may find in most Sunni hadith collection like [al-Muwatta'](http://sunnah.com/malik/3/41), among them a slightly different version in [Sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/4/42).

That means that if we perform a good and concentrated prayer we will be offered what we ask Allah.

Another point that helps on concentration is calmness (الطُّمأْنينة) as our Messenger (peace be upon him) taught the man who didn't pray well in the [hadith](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/79/25). So one shouldn't hasten in the prayer as we've been warned in another [hadith](http://sunnah.com/urn/504060). And we are asked not to turn away, by looking right and left while praying as if we did Allah would stop looking upon us as stated in this [hadith](http://sunnah.com/nasai/13/17). Calmness means as the hadith suggests not to hasten so for example if we perform ruk'u, we shouldn't start reciting the dua' immediately until each part of our body has settled down in the right position ...

My major source in [Arabic](https://saaid.net/rasael/88.htm) and also this [fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/20594) in Arabic, a [fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/45622) with an English translation on the same question but different wording.

And Allah knows best!

Comment: Nice pretty detailed answer. God bless you for expending your time to provide...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be focused in salah, then take note of your recitation and follow the meaning along in your salat. Again whenever you feel that you are out of focus, then say "A 'uzu billahi mina shaidanir rajim" that you seek Allah's refuge from Satan the accused. And spit it 3 times toward your left hand and insha'allah (God willing) you will feel free and focus. (And Allah knows best)

Comment: Please consider adding references to support your claims!

Comment: @Medi1Saif is right, ... ref. / Meanwhile, spit 3times ...?! I reckon it is disrespect to Salah... / As much as I know, tis the view of wahhabis, isn't it?