# Is it permitted to stop praying when I lose concentration?

Tags: salat

I recently heard that breaking in middle of the prayer is a bad thing, but I still don't know how bad it is it, whether it is a serious sin or just a hated action, or whether there are anything from what our Prophet (pbuh) said to support it.

Many times I lose concentration in middle of the prayer, so what I do is say the salam when I completely lose concentration of what I am saying or doing and redo the salat from the beginning.  Is this acceptable?

Comment: Aslam 3leikum Brother, Read my answer it is highly relavant! http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17507/how-to-focus-in-salah/17516#17516

Comment: @ Aboudi can you give me the Arabic version of the last hadith in your post... Jazaka allho rayran

Comment: No problem, ففي صحيح مسلم أن عثمان بن أبي العاص أتى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فقال: يا رسول الله إن الشيطان قد حال بيني وبين صلاتي وقراءتي يلبسها علي، فقال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم ذاك شيطان يقال له خنزب، فإذا أحسسته فتعوذ بالله منه واتفل على يسارك ثلاثاً ، قال: ففعلت ذلك فأذهبه الله عني

Comment: what it exactly means "اتفل على يسارك ثلاثاً" and how to do it?

Comment: Blowing onto your left thrice without actually spitting so it just air, similar to Tfff, Tfff Tfff if that makes any sense

Answer (score 2):

**(1)**. It is Haram (forbidden) to break an obligatory prayer except in certain occasions:

1.For the purpose of protecting his own property or the property whose protection is obligatory on him or escaping from a physical or financial harm

2.For the purpose of protecting his own life or a person's life whose protection is obligatory when doing so is impossible without breaking the prayer.

3.when a creditor is demanding for payment on condition that he has plenty of time for performing his prayer again in the prescribed time as well as being unable to pay off his debt while offering his prayer.

4.when realizing during the prayer that the Mosque is impure (Najis) and having sufficient time to perform it in the prescribed time, he is permitted to break his prayer even if he knows that he will be capable of removing the impurity from the mosque and making it pure (Pak) after finishing the prayer. However, he is obliged to break his prayer when knowing that he won't stand a chance of purifying the mosque after completing the prayer.

**(2)**. There are [certain doubts invalidating prayers](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2237/). For instance, doubt concerning the number of obligatory prayers comprised of 2 Raka'ts (like Fajr prayer) and 3 Raka'ts (Maghrib prayer) makes the prayer null and void.

**(3)**.There are [certain doubts which should be ignored](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2238/). For instance, doubts of a [person who can't help doubting too much](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2242/) in his prayers.

However, the way in which an act of worship is performed has been explained in such details that clear up any confusion one may face when fulfilling his religious duties.

Comment: Where are your resources?

Comment: http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/

Answer (score 1):

**It would be prohibited to break the Salah (obligatory prayers)**. Of course there are some exception for it, So I mention some of them quite briefly:

> 1. to save your life,
> 2. to save your property (a remarkable amount…)

**But you are not allow to break your prayer because of the concentration that..**

With respect to how to concentrate in the prayer, I suggest you to read the site below.

**http://www.al-islam.org/concentration-in-prayer-jameel-kermalli**

Answer (score 1):

*It is a sin to break salah*

- “And if an evil whisper from Shaytaan (Satan) tries to turn you away
  (O Muhammad) (from doing good), then seek refuge in Allah. Verily,
  He is the All‑Hearer, the All‑Knower” [Fussilat 41:36]

Your concentration is being effected  by a shaytan called khanzab narrated by prophet Muhummad  Sallallahu alaihi wasalam;

- Some of the Sahaabah complained about the waswaas that was bothering
  them. Some of the companions of the Messenger of Allah (peace and
  blessings of Allaah be upon him) came to the Prophet (peace and
  blessings of Allaah be upon him) and said to him, ‘We find in
  ourselves thoughts that are too terrible to speak of.’ He said, ‘Are
  you really having such thoughts?’ They said, ‘Yes.’ He said, ‘That is
  a clear sign of faith.’” (Narrated by Muslim).   (Narrated by Muslim,
  132 from the hadeeth of Abu Hurayrah).

Before offering salah you should say

> A oozu billahi minal khanzab

This should keep the shaytan away from you. It isn't just you that is affected by this shaytan, sahaba were also affected by this shaytan not just in salah but while reading Quran as well.

Seek refuge with utmost trust in Allah and this shaytan can't even come near you.
If you stop offering salah and or break it in between, you are then yourself submitting defeat.

Answer (score -2):

It is not a question of being permitted or not. The reason why you pray is more important than the ritual. Sincerity of your prayers is important. If you can't concentrate, you are really not praying. Do not disturb others that are praying.  Seek Allah's forgiveness and pray again when your mind is calm. HE is all forgiving.