# Concentration during Salat

Tags: salat

I struggle to concentrate really badly during salat. I forget how many  Ra'kats I have read. Too many doubts about almost everything. I fear none of my prayers or correct, I don't know what to do.

Comment: It can help to ponder on the meaning of what you're reciting.

Comment: [How to focus in salah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17507/how-to-focus-in-salah) should be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try to be present in your mind during the prayer, and there is prostration for forgetfulness if you make mistakes or forget.

Answer (score -1):

Aslamoaliakum mr.Hussain, this happens with a lot of people and a way to concentrate during salah is that when ever you get any bad thought or other thoughts just say astagfirullah and it will ultimately take you back into salah

Comment: Wa-Alaikamussalaam brother Slueman. Thank you for answer.  1 question regarding saying Astagfirullah during salaat,  will this not affect my salaat?